# Query post types with multiple keys

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query-posts, customization

I'm looking for a way to only show posts results that contain all of the custom fields requested. Not one or the other. I was only able to get results with one array at a time. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        $documents = array(
        'post_type' => 'documents',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'document-type',
                'value' => 'manual',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'document-status',
                'value' => 'current',
            )
        )
     );
        query_posts( $documents );
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'documents' );
        wp_reset_query();
```

I also tried an SQL Query without any luck.

```
         $documents = "
            SELECT wposts.*
            FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
            JOIN $wpdb->postmeta document-status ON
              ( wposts.ID = document-status.post_id AND
                document-status.meta_key = 'document-status' )
            JOIN $wpdb->postmeta document-type ON 
              ( wposts.ID = document-type.post_id AND
                document-type.meta_key = 'document-type' )
            WHERE document-status.meta_value = 'current'
            AND document-type.meta_value = 'manual'
            AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
            AND wposts.post_type = 'documents'
            AND wposts.post_date < NOW()
            ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
            LIMIT 0 , 4
         "; 
         $documents = $wpdb->get_results($documents, OBJECT);
        query_posts( $documents );
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'documents' );
        wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meta_query` has a `relation` parameter just like `tax_query` so:

```
$documents = array(
    'post_type' => 'documents',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'document-type',
            'value' => 'manual',
        ),
       array(
            'key' => 'document-status',
            'value' => 'current',
        )
    )
);
query_posts( $documents );
get_template_part( 'loop', 'documents' );
wp_reset_query();
```