# Querying multiple values from a single key

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, array, meta-query

[Bainternet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2487/bainternet) assisted me [earler](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24848/query-post-types-with-multiple-keys/24850#24850) with the relation AND parameter. What I need to do now is determine how to query multiple vales from a single key. If I try to specify two arrays with the **same key** the query fails. Is there a way to use an array in the value?Something similar to.

```
'value' => array( 'Install Manual', 'User Manual' ),
```

I've searched quite a bit with no results. This is where I'm at so far.

```
$documents = array(
    'post_type' => 'documents',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'document-type',
            'value' => array( 'Install Manual', 'User Manual' ),
        ),
       array(
            'key' => 'document-status',
            'value' => 'current',
        )
    )
);
query_posts( $documents );
get_template_part( 'loop', 'documents' );
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `'compare' => 'IN'`:

```
        'key' => 'document-type',
        'value' => array( 'Install Manual', 'User Manual' ),
        'compare' => 'IN'
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Is there a document somewhere that explains all the different compares available and what they do?

Comment: Here you go: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters I think they're pretty self explanatory, well except BETWEEN and NOT BETWEEN.